# How to handle time consuming ajax requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, optimization, architecture, execution

This is sort of an SE architecture question. The following is a mock-up of a system we are implementing.

[image: mockup]

The above is the way we handle data calls using ajax. The thing is if the call takes too much time to process in the salesforce section, the API manager throws a timeout and the website gets a response which is a timeout error thrown from the API manager.

Thew method I thought of implementing is send the request to the server then the API manager would send me a ID of the big transaction which is handled in the salesforce section. When the front end receive the ID, I'm going to poll the API manager with a separate web service with the given ID to identify whether the transaction is completed successfully. This I need to call periodically since the time of execution is unknown to me!

For an example say, after getting the ID, I would have an ajax call every 5 seconds to know whether the transaction is over or not.

Is this a sensible approach to the problem I'm facing. Since I couldn't control any of the other sections I would like to know my approach is better or not.

Answer (score 1):

It feels sensible enough.

1. Implement some sort of worker queue in the API manager. It exists several ready-to-use solutions that scales very well (eg gearman).
2. Add a webservice to the API manager that makes it possible to get the status of jobs in the worker queue

... and then you could...

*3. Try to remove one of the systems in your model (it contains many possible points of failure). Can the client (web app) communicate directly with the API manager? Or can the worker queue be implemented on the webserver an be made available via an ajax-function in wordpress*

*4. Add websocket support, its way more awesome than polling :)*

Comment: The web app cannot call directly to the API manager! Instead it goes through a PHP layer and then goes to the API manager. The thing is, the saving function is the time consuming part which needs to take place in the Sales force section. I use ajax to send the data to the server and after that the process initiates. The thing is since the saving takes time the API manager throws a timeout exception. If you could explain on the web-socket thing more i would appreciate since I've never implemented a web-socket!

Comment: Websockets makes it possible for the server to push data to the client/browser. It's the technology to use when instant feedback is necessary but the ordinary request/response procedure is not. In your case I'm guessing its not that important. html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics